# Stuck in 'Diplomatic Immunity' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am halfway through the 'Diplomatic Immunity' quest near the start of the game but I can't get any farther because I keep dying. I have tried about 20 times and can't get past some guards.

Is there any way to quit the quest? I can't fast travel out.

I am using the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: Which quest are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: The one where you sneek into the imperial legion as a guest to a party

Comment: Diplomatic Immunity? Where you sneak into the Thalmor Embassy?

Comment: yes that one.__

Comment: On the PC version I would simply lower the difficulty setting. Is that not possible on the console versions?

Comment: The difficulty is on the lowest but I got lucky a with perfectly timed critical hit and got past the quest. I am still interested on how you could get out of a quest if it was impossible to continue

Comment: I think in most cases if you are able to exit the location in any way you can simply select a different quest and come back later. I've had to do this once when I started playing DLC content on too low a level and the enemies we're 15 levels above me.

Comment: afaik you can't leave this area once you have started the quest.

Comment: well i find even with a low-moderate sneak skill any stealth mission can overcome by taking off your boots and constantly saving even the slightest progress.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been doing to blades questline, but I guess it's as simple as just reloading the save when you walk into the sleeping giant inn and not talking to her. If you talked to her and then did other unrelated stuff, find the last save before entering the embassy

Answer (score 1):

If you are beast race, orc, khajiht, argonian, than this won't work, but if you are human you can go close to thalmor in their robes, elves even closer, and a high elf can talk to a certain guard and convince him to take a break and have you take his spot. A spare set of thalmor robes can be found at the beginning in a room on your right after the first 2 guards.

Answer (score 0):

sparks, flame and lots of sneaking.